# Uninstall ubuntu from external Hard Drive with Windows on the main one

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a laptop with an SSD (with Windows 7 on it) and a second HDD on which Ubuntu is installed. I have no more need to have the latter on my PC, so I would like to remove its partitions, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Do I just need to remove the partitions using the Windows partition tool, or are there any other steps I should follow, like for removing GRUB or something like this?

Comment: Make sure you have the windows boot loader as first boot option BEFORE deleting `Ubuntu`. Once Ubuntu is removed, so will be the `grub`. Then proceed using Windows' partition tools.